# Failed to load resource: server responded with a status of 500. SignalR

Tags: asp.net

In localhost, it works fine, but when I publish it to a server it sends me the following error: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500.

In Iss Enabled Service WebSockets and Framework 4.5

Any ideas?

My code is:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalR/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var job = $.connection.myHub;

        job.client.displayStatus = function () {

            getData();
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();

    });

    function getData() {

        var $tbl = $('#tbl');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.aspx/GetData',
            contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                //debugger;
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    var newdata = data.d;
                    $tbl.empty();
                    $tbl.append('<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Qty</th></tr>');
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                        rows.push(' <tr><td>' + newdata[i].id + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Name + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].PricDecimal + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].QuantDecimal + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                    $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                }
            }

        });

    }

</script>
```

My class Hub is:

```
public class MyHub: Hub
{

    public static void Show()
    {

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();

    }

}
```

Comment: well a 500 error just means the server-side script crashed in some way. It's deliberately vague so as not to give away information which might aid someone trying to attack the server. You need to check the server - debug it, or check logs, event viewer etc to find out what the actual error / exception was. Then you might have a better idea how to go about fixing it. Since you mention it works fine in one environment but not the other, the obvious place to start would be by looking for differences in the environment and config which could be relevant to the particular bit of code that crashed